# Influence of an insulator on charged bodies in a vacuum

Tags: electrostatics

If there are two charged bodies kept in a vacuum and an insulator is placed in between them, will there be any effect on the electrostatic force between the two charges?

** (Not part of the question) From which sources I can get in-depth knowledge about this topic? Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit**:[image]
According to the properties of electric field lines mentioned in the image above, shouldn't the number of lines involved in the interaction(force) between two charges reduce due to the presence of the insulator or another charge(third one) in between them? Here I am referring to the interaction between the 1st and 2nd charge only excluding all other interactions

Comment: Hello Ahmed and welcome to Physics SE. It could prove quite helpful to provide some more information on your problem. For example, are the dimensions of the insulator infinite? Can you provide a sketch (even if it is a rough one)? Are you looking for a mathematical formulation or even a qualitative answer would be enough?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the intensity of the electric field in influenced by the $permittivity$ of the insulating material located between two conductors:

https://passive-components.eu/the-dielectric-constant-and-its-effects-on-the-properties-of-a-capacitor/

and

https://web.mit.edu/8.02t/www/802TEAL3D/visualizations/coursenotes/modules/guide05.pdf (cf. figure 5.5.5 and corresponding explanations)